# how does talib.LINEARREG works?

Tags: python, ta-lib

In addition, my question now is if I want to regress on two array which is **not equal spaced** and **unordered**, for example

```
x = np.array([0.1, 0.5, 2.0, 1.6, 2.8, 3.5, 0.9, 1.5])
y = np.array([0.22, 1.21, 4.19, 3.39, 5.85, 7.21, 2.0, 3.2])
```

What should I do by using the LINEARREG function in talib ?

---

Thanks for truf points out the c-code link, LINEARREG only deal with the euqal distance x-array, and regress only by input y-array(close price here).

```
y = array([ 2.,  4.,  6.,  8., 10., 12., 14., 16.])

tb.LINEARREG_INTERCEPT(y,5)
>>> array([nan, nan, nan, nan,  2.,  4.,  6.,  8.])

tb.LINEARREG_SLOPE(y,5)
>>> array([nan, nan, nan, nan,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.])
```

Also one should note that the input numpy array need type check

```
dtype=np.float
```

to match the 'double' in c.

---

> original question

I'm using TA-Lib to calculate technical indicators, but I don't understand the LINEARREG function where only one input array(called close price), usually doing a linear regression, we need two arrays x and y to regress, for example we want to regress close price on return.

real = LINEARREG(close, timeperiod=14)

Answer (score 3):

You better to check the ta-lib's code for this function:
https://sourceforge.net/p/ta-lib/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/ta-lib/c/src/ta_func/ta_LINEARREG.c#l238
It contains following explanation:

```
   /* Linear Regression is a concept also known as the
* "least squares method" or "best fit." Linear
* Regression attempts to fit a straight line between
* several data points in such a way that distance
* between each data point and the line is minimized.
*
* For each point, a straight line over the specified
* previous bar period is determined in terms
* of y = b + m*x:
*
* TA_LINEARREG          : Returns b+m*(period-1)
* TA_LINEARREG_SLOPE    : Returns 'm'
* TA_LINEARREG_ANGLE    : Returns 'm' in degree.
* TA_LINEARREG_INTERCEPT: Returns 'b'
* TA_TSF                : Returns b+m*(period)
*/
```

It seems your close price will be treated as y array and x will be day number array [1..14]. TA_LINEARREG_SLOPE, TA_LINEARREG_ANGLE, TA_LINEARREG_INTERCEPT and TA_TSF are other ta-lib's functions that are based on TA_LINEARREG.